# package graphicx and ifthen problem

Tags: graphics, conditionals

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[final,pdftex]{graphicx}
\newboolean{GraphicsDraft}
\setboolean{GraphicsDraft}{true}
\newcommand{\nograph}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{GraphicsDraft}}
  {true}%
  {false}%
}%nograph

\begin{document}
\includegraphics*[draft=\nograph]{pic} % This gives an error
%
\renewcommand\nograph{\ifGraphicsDraft true\else false\fi}
\includegraphics*[draft=\nograph]{pic} % This is OK
\end{document}
```

An ifthenelse is problematic whereas the \ifGraphicsDraft works

Am I doing something stupid or is this a real bug

Comment: It appears that \nograph is \protected.  \edef\test{\nograph} fails while \def\test{\nograph} can be printed.

Comment: It's not a bug; it's how `\ifthenelse` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an expandable test, which `\ifthenelse` isn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{GraphicsDraft}
\togglefalse{GraphicsDraft}

\newcommand{\nograph}{%
  \iftoggle{GraphicsDraft}{true}{false}%
}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[draft=\nograph]{example-image-a}

\toggletrue{GraphicsDraft}

\includegraphics[draft=\nograph]{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for pointing this out to me.
I hesitate to use etoolbox for just one toggle,
especially where
    \newcommand\nograph{\ifGraphicsDraft true\else false\fi}
does what is expected.

@David Carlisle
Being part of a bigger machinery, I can't easily use your suggestion
    \newcommand\nograph{true}
That's the price one has to pay for a minimal example:-)
But I'll reconsider that at due time.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `draft` key has to *expand* to true or false, and `\ifthenelse` does not work via expansion. It fails for the same reason that

```
\includegraphics[draft=\def\tmp{true}\tmp]
```

fails, even though `\def\tmp{true}\tmp` would typeset `true`.

You could, as you indicate use

```
\renewcommand\nograph{\ifGraphicsDraft true\else false\fi}
```

or simpler not have a switch at all and instead of having

```
\setboolean{GraphicsDraft}{true}
```

or

```
\setboolean{GraphicsDraft}{true}
```

Just have

```
\newcommand\nograph{true}
```

or

```
\newcommand\nograph{false}
```

Then `\nograph` directly expands to true or false.